# how to extract specific word from string in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Product name contains words deliminated by space.
First word is size second in brand etc.

How to extract those words from string, e.q how to implement query like:

```
select
  id,       
  getwordnum( prodname,1 ) as size,
  getwordnum( prodname,2 ) as brand
  from products
where ({0} is null or getwordnum( prodname,1 )={0} ) and
    ({1} is null or getwordnum( prodname,2 )={1} )


create table product ( id char(20) primary key, prodname char(100) );
```

How to create getwordnum() function in Postgres or should some substring() or other function used directly in this query to improve speed ?

Comment: What "just somebody" is trying to say: your database model is wrong. Read up on normalization

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try to use function **split_part**

```
select
  id,       
  split_part( prodname, ' ' , 1 ) as size,
  split_part( prodname, ' ', 2 ) as brand
  from products
where ({0} is null or split_part( prodname, ' ' , 1 )= {0} ) and
    ({1} is null or split_part( prodname, ' ', 2 )= {1} )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably `split_part` which is available as a String function in PostgreSQL. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id,       
    prodname[1] as size,
    prodname[2] as brand
from (
    select
        id,
        regexp_split_to_array(prodname, ' ') as prodname
    from products
) s
where
    ({0} is null or prodname[1] = {0})
    and
    ({1} is null or prodname[2] = {1})
```